# Looking for samples of using DotNetOpenAuth with WebAPI

Tags: c#, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to secure my WebAPI project, and would like to use DotNotOpenAuth, but I'm unable to find any quality samples or tutorials. I've tried grabbing the sample that come with the DNOA source on GitHub, but can't seem to get those running correctly. What would be fantastic would be a quick walk through on using DNOA from the ground up authenticating against google/twitter/facebook whoever.

Comment: Create a new MVC project in VS2012 and you'll get a good example from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DotNetOpenAuth is hosted on github. It means you will find there not only samples, but also source code, and other interesting things

https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth

When speaking about samples and Web API, there is only one sample project:

OAuth2ProtectedWebApi 
https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/samples/OpenIdProviderMvc

You can find there also ASP.NET MVC samples. It will be usefull, as ASP.NET MVC is pretty similar to Web API.

When you have more question, as source for your answers and discussions try to consider DotNetOpenAuth group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/dotnetopenid